# AWS.Rekognition is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, angular2, amazon-web-services

Всем привет,использую Angular 2. Обращаюсь к rekognition и ошибка AWS.Rekognition is not a constructor.

```
 var rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition({apiVersion: '2016-06-27'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, Вы используется умолчальный билд AWS SDK for JavaScript. Он не включает поддержку Rekognition (из-за того, что не поддерживает CORS). Надо собрать собственный билд SDK на https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало)